# How to Integrate Uber Uploader in PHP project in windows server?

Tags: php, file-upload

i ahave a form in which i need to upload the files of 50 mb, for which I want to use Uber uploader as it supports upload more than 10mb , but I am unaware of how to integrate the uber uploader in my project.. I am new to this and PECL and APC things used in project, I also cam to know that it needs linux server, which my client dont have he uses windows server..
please guideme to integrate the uber uploader into my php project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it really need to be that particular product? It looks pretty complicated to set up from what I can see, and setting up APC and a Linux server just to have a upload progress bar sounds a bit over the top.

Is using a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) an option at all? I don't know how it behaves for uploads that big but I expect it should work fine. Will be easy enough to find out.

If you want to stick with Uber Uploader, however, the `INSTALL_AND_FAQ.HTML` file in the download package should give you some first guidance.

Comment: I need the easiest solution for this if u can help me with this, @Porter "INSTALL AND_FAQ.HTML" is confusing me...

Comment: I need to accomplish two things with it, firstly to upload the 50mb file and seconldy displaying Progress bar to user

Comment: @OM I can't help you with Uber Uploader I'm afraid, I have never used it myself... I would take a look at SWFUpload, it should be easier to set up.

Comment: @Pekka Can I use it for file size of 50  mb? as i found it prety simpelr than Uber..

Comment: @Om as I said I haven't tried, but it seems to work okay for even much larger files for many users (see e.g. http://www.google.com/#q=swfupload+limitations&hl=de&safe=off&start=10&sa=N&fp=27880074e17f4153) you may have to adjust your server's maximum upload size: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody